# compilation error: cocoapods xcode test project compilation error, how to remove test project cleanly

Tags: xcode, testing, cocoapods

The question is how to cleanly remove Test in cocoapods PodFile ?

I'ved just recently updated cocoapods 1.0.0 to my project

I ran "pod init" to generate a sample PodFile then put in my pods.

Whole bunch of error generated by the xcode test project ProjectNameTests
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwKUt.jpg

How can I cleanly remove the tests ? Even if comment it out there is other problems like Bridging-Header.h cannot find dependent header.

In my current PodFile for 1.0.0:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ProjectName

    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit',  '~> 4.9'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.1'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'AWSS3'

  target 'ProjectNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

my previous PodFile, no mention for target project or test:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit',  '~> 4.9'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.9'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.1'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'AWSS3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of errors you'r defining are not because you have a target to the tests in your Podfile. **inherit! :search_paths** indicates that this target inherits the pods from the target above it.

One thing you might be getting wrong is that the "target '**ProjectName**' do" is not regarding your project name but an actual target of your project.

A target can have a different name then your project. 
You can also check the official migration guide [Migration Guide](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0-Migration-Guide/).

Comment: Im really confused with this. All the errors are under the test target http://imgur.com/fUOF18i. I'ved updated how previous and current PodFile looks like. Im running blank on this as Im not quite sure why all the errors are in test target. Should I find a way to remove the test target ?? Thanks

Comment: but you are right about something, eventhough the errors are in test target but the errors are related to code like "use of undeclared type 'baseservice'". im confused to how to solve this

Comment: inherit! :search_paths was generated from pod init

Comment: all the targets i checked are correct, if i rename it, it will produce an error saying these are the existing targets

Comment: For example, this "class UserService: BaseService " is related to AlomaFire. Its something on this dependencies that is causing the Test target. How do I fix it ? Thanks